# My java program isn't counting database rows correctly

Tags: java, mysql

I'm making a program and I have to get the number of rows in a MySQL database. My table has 4 rows but for some reason I'm getting the number 1 everytime I run the program. Here is my code:

```
public static void showItems() throws Exception {
    try{
        Connection con = getConnection();
        Statement search = con.createStatement();
        ResultSet rs = search.executeQuery("SELECT COUNT(id) FROM main;");
        int rows = 0;
        rs.beforeFirst();
        while (rs.next()){
            rows++;
        }
        System.out.println(rows);
```

Can someone help me? What am I doing wrong here?
I tried many different ways and none returns me the correct value.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your query returns one row and contains the value 4 (the count of the number of rows in the table).

Run your query directly in a database client and look at what you get.

This bit of code should show you how to get ahold of the "4". Try this loop in place of the one that contains "row++":

```
while (rs.next()) {
    System.out.println(rs.getInt(1));
}
```

Comment: I ran it directly on the MySQL Console and I get the value 4. How could I pass this value to the java program?

Comment: I added a bit of code to the answer. Use `rs.getInt(1)` to get the value.

Comment: Ahh. Now I see. I was getting the row count 1 instead of its value... Thank you Rob!